# Grounding question

Tags: grounding, wire

I'm replacing track lighting with slim recessed led lights. Metal electric box has black wire, white and there is a twisted copper wire that is not secured to anything. Pretty sure thatis my ground but where should it be attached?

Comment: What electrical box? Are you talking about a junction box in the ceiling or part of the light fixture? Please revise to be more clear where the wires you're describing reside. A photo would be great.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. As noted, please [edit] your post to include some additional details and a pic of the current light and wiring and the new light and the inside of the box you're mounting it to will be very helpful. Once you've done that, take the [tour] to learn how to make the most out of this Q&A site and avoid the "discussion forum" pitfalls that manage to bite some newcomers.

Answer (score 1):

The bare twisted wires in the metal box are your ground wires , with metal boxes they should be connected to the box and if your new lights have a green ground or bare copper connect that to the bare wires in the box also. The black is the hot and white neutral with only 3 in there and wired to code.

Comment: @Byron the bare metal should wire be screwed tightly to the box, there is a special screw for it against the back wall of the box. Go around that screw once, tighten the screw, and continue the wire into a twist-on cap, where you also add the green from your lighting

Comment: 10-32 green machine screw with self forming Threads (not tapping) .